# Getters vs State; Mutations vs Actions

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Вопрос. В чём принципиальная разница между использованием двух похожих примитивов:

- getters и state
- mutations и actions

Мне не ясно, зачем использовать `getters`, если можно напрямую обратиться к state. Аналогично, зачем использовать синхронные `mutations`, когда есть `await` и асинхронные `actions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Геттеры, состояние, мутации, действия - это не примитивы (как по отдельности, так и попарно), а части единой системы, которую представляет собой экземпляр Vuex. Каждая из этих частей выполняет свою собственную роль... поэтому, неразумно сравнивать их: эти части **не** взаимозаменяемые.

Мутации нужны для изменения состояния, действия - для вычислений перед этими изменениями, а геттеры - для оптимизированного и удобного доступа к данным состояния. Все это объясняется в [официальной документации Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/).

Геттеры работают как вычисляемые (computed) свойства, обладая всеми их преимуществами.
В целом, для получения данных из стейта всегда лучше использовать геттеры, а не прямое обращение - потому что, помимо выигрыша на оптимизации чтения (выполняемой Vue), геттеры представляют собой "централизованный интерфейс" к данным. Благодаря такой организации, схему (и даже архитектуру) хранилища при необходимости можно менять, не внося изменения отдельно в каждый читающий компонент (которых, в серьезных веб-приложениях, десятки... плюс, помимо компонентов, еще интеграционные тесты хранилища).

А изменение состояния в действиях, даже полностью синхронных - это наиужаснейший антипаттерн из всех что можно придумать. Хотя бы из-за того, что это исключает [подписку на изменения](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/api/#subscribe), и [отладку Vuex](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd)... другими словами, это огромный шаг к write-only коду.
Любая запись в хранилище должна выполняться строго через мутации.

---

<sub>*Лично мне абсолютно непонятно, зачем вообще набираться ошибок из мутных статей (и особенно на хабре!), когда официальная документация предоставляет всю нужную информацию... и она пишется при участии тех людей, которые разработали библиотеку. Кому, как не авторам, знать о ее правильном использовании?*</sub>

Comment: Окей, какая мотивация стоит за тем, чтобы всюду использовать геттеры? В доке написано -- ок. Но зачем? Дополнительный копипаст

Comment: @hedgehogues, Мотивация в более поддерживаемом коде: _"Благодаря такой организации, схему (и даже архитектуру) хранилища при необходимости можно менять, не внося изменения отдельно в каждый читающий компонент"_ - если же использовать прямое чтение, даже мелкие изменения создают лишнюю работу. Иногда мало, а иногда тонны.

Comment: @hedgehogues, Плюс к тому, не обязательно создавать геттер на каждое свойство - можно (и зачастую нужно) возвращать композитный объект с их логической группировкой (по роли данных, либо их использованию в компонентах). Из-за кэширования вычисляемых результатов, этот объект будет фактически пересоздаваться только при изменении значений свойств (зависимостей геттера).

Comment: а, так вот... геттер умеет кэшировать, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @hedgehogues, Да.

Answer (score 0):

Краткий ответ:

`getters` следует использовать в том случае, если в state явно не хранится информация и её нужно вычислить. Иными словами `state` -- это модель данных, а `getters` -- это способ преобразования этих данных. Не стоит писать на каждый чих отдельный геттер. Можно напрямую обращаться к `state`.

`mutations` следует использовать в тех случаях, когда нужно изменить значение переменной. Важно использовать именно `mutations`, а не нативный `state`, поскольку `mutations` отслеживает движок `vuejs` и все пакеты и плагины следят за ними, а `state` для них невидимые. `actions` же чаще всего используются для реализации бизнес-логики, а также для получения данных из внешних источников. Таким образом, `mutations` -- работа с моделью данных, а `actions` -- работа с внешними данными и преобразованием данных перед записью.

Детально можно прочесть здесь:

[О геттерах](https://habr.com/ru/post/440542/) и почему их не стоит использовать во vuex.

И обязательно прочтите комменты. Там есть очевидные вещи, но, увы, я про них забываю.

Я бы советовал изучать так:

1. https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/
2. https://habr.com/ru/post/440542/
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39299042/vuex-action-vs-mutations
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52386161/vuex-when-to-use-getters-and-when-to-use-state

Важные вопросы.

- Общий подход к разработке с vuex (1-2)
- Когда следует использовать mutations, а когда getters? (3)
- Когда следует напрямую обращаться к state, а когда — использовать getters? (4)

Также, я оставлю несколько ссылок, которые мне помогли понять суть. Они должны быть понятны начинающему:

- https://habr.com/ru/post/421551/
- https://medium.com/@KucherDev/vuex-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-6807d9ad330d
- https://habr.com/ru/post/322354/

Comment: #2 - крайне вредная статья. Ее автор не приводит никаких доводов к тем бредням, что выдает за истину.